# How to design buttons  in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have 2 screens. My first screen is loading a second screen. The second screen has the subject's name in a table view. I want to add 3 buttons at the bottom of simulator ( not below the table). These 3 buttons will act as a filter. When the user clicks on the first button, whole books will be filtered by that button event. How will I add the buttons? I want to make the buttons visible to users for any number of rows in table view.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add *UIToolbar* with three *UIBarButtonItems* at the bottom of your view. [This tutorial](http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/navigation-controller-uitoolbar/) may help  you further!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Segment controls with 3 segments and reload tableview on click of each button

code

```
- (NSInteger )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //different rows for each section and for different selected segment value
 switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
     case 0:
         return [arrayOfRestaurants count]; //counting number of restaurants
         break;
    case 1:
        return [arrayOfHotels count]; //counting number of hotels

             break;

    case 2:
         return [arrayOfPlaces count]; //counting number of famous place
             break;


 }
    return 0;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;



    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];// cell intialization

    [cell.textLabel setFont:kFont];

    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:80/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0]];

    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    //set up cell for different selected segments...

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"For Restaurants List");
            Restaurants *restaurants = [arrayOfRestaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //getting list of restaurants

             //setting name of restaurnats to string

            cell.textLabel.text = restaurants.Name;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = restaurants.Address; //detail textlabel to display address
            break;

        case 1:
            NSLog(@"For Hotels List");
            Hotel *hotels = [arrayOfHotels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //getting list of hotels
            cell.textLabel.text = hotels.Name;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = hotels.Address;//address of hotel
            break;

        case 2:
            NSLog(@"For Places List");
            Famousplaces *famousPlaces = [arrayOfPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//getting list of famous places
            cell.textLabel.text = famousPlaces.Name; //name of famous place
            break;

    }   

    return cell;



}

//segment control value changed method
- (IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged {

    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            [tableView reloadData];//reloading table on selected segment
            break;

            case 1:
            [tableView reloadData];

                break;

            case 2:
            [tableView reloadData];
                break;

        default:
            break;
    }




}
```